# How to use AHK to hold down the mouse click as long as I'm holding it?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, autohotkey

Here is my code atm..

```
; Create hotkey for the 'left' key
left::
Click , 53, 486
return

; Create hotkey for the 'down' key
down::
Click , 138, 613
return

; Create hotkey for the 'right' key
right::
Click , 227, 543 
return

; Create hotkey for the 'up' key
up::
Click , 136, 476
return
```

I tried using Click {Down up} or {Up down} but it holds it down forever.. How do I make it those button hold down as long as I hold down my arrow keys? And stop when I release the arrow keys? Sorry I'm very confused and new :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
left::
send,{Lbutton down}
keywait,left
Send,{Lbutton up}
return
```

You need the `keywait` command because AHK will only allow one of the same hotkeys to run at a time, the keywait ensures that the current hotkey does not end until you let go of the key. Thus when the autorepeat does kick in AHK does not fire the hotkey again because it is already running.